Issue with Audio Tag Actions Displaying Incorrectly in Google Chrome 125.0.6422.112
For the Google chrome version 125.0.6422.112, We are facing an issue with audio tag in our portal i.e if we click the actions functionality (three dots) for a specific audio tag, it show the options for another tag, instead of the selected tag.
The HTML code for the same is attached below with the screenshot.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        td {
            padding: 12px 24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Audio</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="horse.mp3" download>Download</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="horse.mp3" download>Download</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample</td>
            <td>March</td>
            <td>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="horse.mp3" download>Download</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>


Below image shows the problem (1st image) and the expected result (2nd image)

I tried to google this problem but looks like its new issue and haven't found any proper solution.
Please guide. Thanks in advance.
